# Are algorithms rated on the big-o notation affected by parallelism?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, big-o

I've just read an article about a breakthrough on matrix multiplication; an algorithm that is O(n^2.373). But I guess matrix multiplication is something that can be parallelized. So, if we ever start producing thousandth-cores processors, will this become irrelevant? How would things change?

Comment: That algorithm is only a theoretical breakthrough; as far as I know even the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm is not used in practice.

Comment: There is n log^2(n) algorithm for mesh based architecture, with n processor, for matrix multiplication (theoretically), also there are too many algorithms which are independent from their normal `O`, when you want to think about parallel algorithms, you should think about other ways, normal ways normally are useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If quantum computing comes to something practical some day, then yes, complexity of algorithms will change.

In the meantime, parallelizing an algorithm, with a fixed number of processors, just divides its runtime proportionally (and that, in the best case, when there are no dependencies between the tasks performed at every processor). That means, dividing the runtime by a constant, and so the complexity remains the same.

Comment: The complexity of algorithms won't change; the time complexity of certain _problems_, for solution using a quantum computer, will be found to be applicable - that's all.

Answer (score 16):

Parallel execution doesn't change the basics of the complexity for a particular algorithm -- at best, you're just taking the time for some given size, and dividing by the number of cores. This may reduce time for a given size by a constant factor, but has no effect on the algorithm's complexity.

At the same time, parallel execution does sometimes change *which* algorithm(s) you want to use for particular tasks. Some algorithms that work well in serial code just don't split up into parallel tasks very well. Others that have higher *complexity* might be faster for practical-sized problems because they run better in parallel.

For an extremely large number of cores, the complexity of the calculation itself may become secondary to simply getting the necessary data to/from all the cores to do the calculation. most computations of big-O don't take these effects into account for a serial calculation, but it can become quite important for parallel calculations, especially for some models of parallel machines that don't give uniform access to all nodes.

Answer (score 5):

By [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), **for the same size of problem**, parallelization will come to a point of diminishing return with the increase in the number of cores (theoretically). In reality, from a certain degree of parallelization, the overhead of parallelization will actually decrease the performance of the program.

However, by [Gustafson's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law), the increase of number of cores actually helps as the size of the problem increases. That is the motivation behind cluster computing. As we have more computing power, we can tackle problem at a larger scale or better precision with the help of parallelization.

Algorithms that we learn as is may or may not be paralellizable. Sometimes, a separate algorithm must be used to efficiently execute the same task in parallel. Either way, the Big-O notation must be re-analyze for the parallel case to take into consideration the effect of parallelization on the time complexity of the algorithm.