# Big O Notation of indeterminate number of values running in parallel

Tags: loops, big-o

If I have a parameter n<=10, the loop can never be greater than that, and I have 4 instances of that running, would it be:

`O(max{f(n), g(n), h(n), i(n)})`

Or

`O(n)`?

For example:
(4 parallel processes)

```
for n in maessages:
  print(n)
```

Or
(All 4 in a loop)

```
for n in queues:
  for m in messages:
    print(m)
```

I was thinking that it would be `O(n)` since they would all be running at the same time and getting `n` data.

I also understand that running these 4 instances in a single program creates an additional outer for loop that is also `O(n)`, so that would make it `O(n * m)`.

So, which is it? And why?

PS. Not homework.

Comment: In your first example, you have `n` messages. If you run them in two sets in parallel, you still have `n` items. The `n` in your second example should be something else, say `o`. Then you have either `O(n)` or `O(o*m)` but they're the same thing because `n == o*m`. So `O(n)` is always `O(n)` regardless of parallelization.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think this may also have helped. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173804/4522447

Comment: "If I have a parameter n<=10" - if the size of the input is bound by a constant, the complexity should be O(1) IMHO.

Comment: Oh, and a legitimate `O(n*m)` algorithm is `O(n*m)` because `n` and `m` are unrelated.